# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

I am trying to build an application, Aseprite, based on instructions that are here:
http://rtonare.net/w/aseprite
which are very similar to the official documentation here:
https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/master/INSTALL.md
except using VS 2013. Apparently this should work, according to the developer.

Except I keep getting a linker error:
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup C:\Users\Travis\Documents\Development\aseprite\build\src\gen\MSVCRT.lib(crtexew.obj)    gen
Error   6   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Travis\Documents\Development\aseprite\build\src\gen\RelWithDebInfo\gen.exe 1   1   gen

and I really do not know what is going on. Most of the posts I have seen about his error recommend setting the subsystem to from /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS to /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE but this is not a console application.

I did look into the code a little bit, in the main application file main.cpp this is shown as the entry point:

```
// Aseprite entry point. (Called from she library.)
    int app_main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
     ...
     ...
     ...
    }
```

which is called by the she library, which I believe is part of the Allegro game engine this uses.

I really have no idea where to start, never encountered this problem before and it looks to be related to the entry point, possibly, and other solutions do not seem applicable.

Comment: If you're certain that's meant to be the entry point you can define the entry point in linker options. Or just define `WinMain` and call `app_main` from there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with cmake not generating the VS solution correctly. You should try to build aseprite with NMake.

https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/issues/541